# sqlite3 unixtime interval query by multiplication and division

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have been trying to create a query for my sqlite3 database that provides me with a count of all records at 10 minute intervals between a maximum and minimum time.

I found this answer on the internet, and it seems to work:

```
select (((`unixtime`)/600000)*600000) as timeslice, 
count(*) as mycount from mytable 
where 
`unixtime` >= 1413902772599 
and 
`unixtime` <= 1413972793000 
group by timeslice;
```

The result I get is something like this:

```
timeslice      mycount   
-------------  ----------
1413930000000  9         
1413930600000  1013      
1413931200000  265       
1413932400000  410       
1413933000000  643
```

This seems like sort of a hackish way to go about doing this query. It also doesn't include datapoints that have a zero count, which is an edge-case that I am going to have to fix outside of the database scope (unless there is an SQL solution for this).

Is there a better way to go about this? Are there edge cases for this if I proceed to continue using this query? Will this catastrophically fail under certain scenarios that I'm not considering?

Comment: What is hackish about this? Which SQLite version are you using? (And why the MySQL tag?)

Comment: Perhaps "hackish" is a bad word. SQL is a very expressive language and the code used to arrive at the result I'm getting isn't obviously indicative of the response. I'm looking for a function or set of functions that achieve this result without edge-cases. I removed the MySQL tag, it was misclicked on the suggested tags. I am running Sqlite 3.8.2 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Why are you dividing by 600000 and then multiplying by 600000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no better way to round to multiples of 600000; SQLite has the [round() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#round), but you would still need to convert to/from a value that *can* be rounded to some decimal fraction.

If you had SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you could use a [recursive common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to generate the intervals:

```
WITH RECURSIVE intervals(t) AS (
    VALUES(1413902400000)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t + 600000
    FROM intervals
    WHERE t < 1413972000000
)
SELECT intervals.t,
       COUNT(*)
FROM intervals
LEFT JOIN MyTable
    ON MyTable.unixtime BETWEEN intervals.t
                            AND intervals.t + 599999
GROUP BY 1;
```